# how do I know user info submited?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i have http://jsfiddle.net/bd9wv/... what i am trying to do is have boxes users can input numbers in, and be able to comment back based on the numbers they gave..what i have works for one only...if someone would not mind telling me...what holds the input, i think it's var val? i think i should be able to add more boxes. exp... `var al id="number1" type="text"/>` ...and then in js..... `msg = 'Thank you for the wonderful number: ' + (val+al);` but that does not work for me. i would like maybe 10 boxes..but 2-3 is good for me to see how it is done. what i am not understanding is what holds the input and how to use it...explaning a little would be great, i think the submit might be getting me. but if you have an example i can look at it an figure it out,i will be very thankful!!

```
$('#someButton').click(function () {
        var val = $('#inputFieldId').val();
        var $outputDiv = $('#outputFieldId');
        var msg = '';
        if (! $.isNumeric(val)) {
            msg = 'Please enter a valid number';
        }
        else if (parseInt(val, 10) > 100) {
            msg = 'Enter number less than 100';        
        }
        else {
            msg = 'Thank you for the wonderful number: ' + val;
        }
        $outputDiv.text(msg);
}
```

Comment: What "does not work" for you? Are you getting an unexpected result? An error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping much of your code in place you can make this work. I changed your ID's to classes, since there will be multiple similar elements. I modified a piece of your JS to the following:

```
var val = $(this).prev(".number").val();
var $outputDiv = $(this).next().next(".feedback");
```

Using `this` you can find the closest elements to the `input` the user was typing.

And your HTML:

```
Enter number: <input class="number" type="text"/>
<button class="btnNumber">Submit</button>
<br/>
Feedback: <div class="feedback"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bd9wv/1/

Comment: i am looking to be able to add all of the inputs together. so only need one submit. something like this but without using prompt exp. http://jsfiddle.net/philyphil/DwCRh/

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand clearly; but please try whether this work for you or no http://jsfiddle.net/bd9wv/2/

Example:

```
var val = $(this).parent().find('.number').val();
```

Here I have used class and have surround the html block with another `div`

Comment: ....sorry i am looking to be able to do something like this but with boxes and prompts. jsfiddle.net/philyphil/DwCRh....  i think the html <input class="number" type="text"/> and that type of stuff is messing me up. i kind of understand html and understand js pretty good. just learning jQuery. so that might be getting me to. i am confused what is holding the input and and how it gets put to the div or where ever it is being put. sorry i am not more clear

Comment: Please change your question then